# Topologies not induced by a metric

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Assume that I have a space, a metric, and a possible topology on that space. The topology induced by that metric is not the possible topology.

However, we know: that, if a sequence converges in the metric, it converges in the possible topology (hypothesis). This gives us that the possible topology is finer. This is the first fact (conclusion).

We also know that, for every sequence that converges in the possible topology, one can extract a subsequence that converges in the metric. This is the second fact (hypothesis)

What additional information (conclusions) does this second fact give you? Is it that relatively compact sets in the possible topology are relatively compact in the metric, or can we say more than this? This last fact is because, given a sequence in a relatively compact in the possible topology, we know we can extract a convergent subsequence by relative compactness, and we can extract a convergent subsubsequence by the property I described, hence we have that the set is relatively compact in the metric.

I have had a colleague say that “the closures of the topologies coincide”, this did not make any sense to me because I lack a definition of what the closure of a topology is.

Comment: Your colleague probably wanted to say that the closure operator $A\mapsto\overline{A}$ for both topologies coincide. Which I don't think is true, because as far as I remember coinciding closure operators is equivalent to topologies being equal. But it is very likely that sequential closure operators coincide.

Comment: Let's call $\tau$ the topology and $d$ the metric. I can see that the first condition on sequences implies that $\overline A^\tau\supseteq \overline A^d$, but I don't see why it should imply that $\tau$ is *finer*. See for instance $\tau$ the product topology on the bounded functions and $d$ the sup norm on the same set. If anything, it would suggest that $\tau$ is coarser (fewer closed sets imply larger closures) but I'm not exactly sure off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Your first fact is false.

Let $X$ be any set. Let $\tau_d$ be a metric topology and $\tau$ be any topological space.

Let for every sequence $(x_n) \to x$ in $(X, \tau_d) $ implies $(x_n)\to x$ in $(X, \tau) $.Then $Id:(X, \tau_d) \to (X, \tau) $ is sequentially continuous. Since $(X, \tau_d) $ is first countable, $Id:X\to X$ is topological continuous . Hence $\tau\subset \tau_d$

Hence metric topology $\tau_d$ is finer than than the topology $\tau$. Infact we can choose $\tau, \tau_d$ such that $\tau$ is strictly finer than $\tau$ .

Example : Let $X$ be any uncountable set.

$\tau_d :=\tau_{\text{dis}}=\mathcal{P}(X)$

$\begin{align}\tau&:=\tau_{\text{coc}}\\&
=\{U\subset X : U=\emptyset \text { or} |X\setminus U|\le \aleph_{0}\}\end{align}$

Then $(X, \tau_{\text{dis}}) $ and $(X, \tau_{\text{coc}}) $ has same collection of convergent sequence ( all eventually constant sequences). Hence it satisfy  your given condition. However $\tau_{\text{coc}}\subset\tau_{\text{dis}}$ strictly finer as only proper closed sets in $(X, \tau_{\text{coc}})$ are countable sets.

---

The above example is also satisfy second condition . But contradict your "colleague's" conclusion as any proper subset of $X$  in the space $(X,\tau_{\text{coc}})$ either closed ( in case of countable sets) or dense (in case of uncountable sets) . In other words $\forall A\subset X$ , $\operatorname{Cl}_{\tau_{coc}}(A)= A\text{ or} X$.But in $(X, \tau_{dis}) $ only dense subset is $X$ itself.

Let, $A\subset X$ be any proper uncountable set. Then $\operatorname{Cl}_{\tau_{coc}}(A)=  X$ but $\operatorname{Cl}_{\tau_{dis}}(A)= A$

Hence " closures of the topologies coincide” is false.

Comment: I took it back. But I do have some questions if that’s OK:

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: (1) What is dis? I.e., you claim that the topology given by the power set induced by a distance dis, what is that distance?

Comment: $\tau_{dis}$ is the discrete topology, generated by the discrete metric where every subset is open.

Comment: (2) What additional assumptions could you make, such as maybe Hausdorff and first countable, to get that the “sequentially finer” topology (i.e., the possible topology in my example, the one for which every sequence which converges in the metric converges in the topology but not vice versa,) is finer (in the usual sense)?

Comment: (3) Does the second fact give you any other conclusion? Such as the closures of sets coinciding, under further hypotheses (again e.g. second countable, Hausdorff), or relative compact sets coinciding (if I was right)?

Comment: Ps: please make a small edit to your answer so I can upvote it

Comment: The above counter example satisfy both the conditions and support your conclusion : because both the topological spaces has the same collection of compact sets ( all finite subsets). But an example is not enough. I am trying to generalize the whole of my ideas. I will inform you  about my progress. The answer was just my initial thought.

Comment: Thanks! I am just posting a new question

Comment: $\tau_{coc}$ is known as cocountable topology.

Comment: I don’t think so. The original question had a flaw, but fixing that flaw notwithstanding, the question has not been aswered yet. The question was “what additional information does the existence of a convergent subsequence give you?”

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488799/extracting-converging-subsequences

Here I have refined my question, though

Comment: If you really want answer, then you can start bounty to attract views and answer. It's an interesting question .

Comment: Actually your assertion my colleague was not right is incorrect. The second fact does imply that the closures coincide, in your example it must not be true that every sequence that converges in the possible topology has a convergent subsequence in the metric, hence it’s not an applicable example

Comment: Class of Convergent sequences in both spaces are same namely all eventually constant sequences. Collecting even indices terms we can extract a convergent subsequence. Isn't it?

Comment: Take the following argument: take a set $A$. We want to prove $A^1=A^2$, where $A^1$ is the closure in the poss. top. and $A^2$ the closure in the metric. Take $x_n \in A^2$, then $\exists (x_n)_{n\ge0}\in A$s.t. $x_n \to x$ in the metric, hence $x_n \to x$ in the topology. Hence $x\in A_1$. Conversely, take $x_n \in A^1$, then $\exists (x_n)_{n\ge0}\in A$s.t. $x_n \to x$ in the topology, hence a $\exists$ a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\ge0}$ s.t. $ x_{n_k} \to x$ in the metric. Hence, $x\in A^2$.

Comment: “Take $x\in A^1$“ and “Take $x\in A^2$“, not “Take $x_n$“

Comment: Sorry, but that was indeed an assumption. You said “it may not imply it”, but I assumed it does. Hence why I stated it as a fact.

Comment: It is there as the second fact, symbols are not necessarily better than words